# Maximum number of lenses displayable in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: lenses

What is the maximum number of lens the heads up display will shown in Ubuntu 12.10? I would like to know, and I am sure other would as well. I don't want to install more than allowable or usable.

Comment: Lenses are not used by the HUD, they are filters for the Unity Dash.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of an existing limitation. I have seen screenshots of Dash screens with every available lens displayed, so I think you can install at least 10-15 lenses without running into problems.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you can backup your 10-15 figure with a fact - link to the source code where 10-15 is stated?

Comment: True, but my answer is based on experience, not on knowldge of the code.

Comment: I have installed lenses on a test machine about a month ago, and came to an odd finding. Now realize this was on the last beta release of 12.10. Once I got up to around 11 or 12 lenses as I installed one, one of the earlier ones I had installed would no longer be visible in the heads up display. So I am thinking either there is a limit or a setting.

Comment: Or maybe some just get out of the visible range and can only be summoned by a shortcut?

Comment: That is one possibility. I cannot find any information on that option. It would be nice if we could size the HUD to accommodate our preferences and lens usage.

Comment: Update - I have installed 14 lenses so far without an issue. I will update this as I progress.

Answer (score 0):

Theres actually a way to resize the unity dash, once you open, you can click the maximize buttom in top-left of it. If you dont like it maximized, you can always Ctrl+Tab to navigate thru them once the dash is open.